# how do I concatenate a script in a workflow job by script console in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, console-application, jenkins-groovy

I have a list of workflow jobs thats contains the script: `println("hello");`

And I can return, in string, the value of the scripts with the bellow code:

```
for (job in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getView(nomeView).items) {
  if (job.name.contains("myJobs")) {
    script = job.getDefinition().getScript();
    println(script);
  }
}
```

result:

```
println("hello");
println("hello");
println("hello");
println("hello");
println("hello");
println("hello");
println("hello");
... number of jobs
```

But I not want only to get the script but modify it.

```
script = job.getDefinition().getScript();
job.getDefinition().setScript(script + "println("world");"; //there are something like this?
println(script);
```

I expect the result be this:

```
println("hello");
println("world");
println("hello");
println("world");
println("hello");
println("world");
println("hello");
println("world");
... number of jobs
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowDefinition

for (job in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getView(nomeView).items) {
  if (job.name.contains("myJobs")) {
    script = job.getDefinition().getScript();
    println(script);

    job.setDefinition(new CpsFlowDefinition(script + "println("world");", true)
    script_new = job.getDefinition().getScript();
    println(script_new);

  }
}
```